# Showing Co-Authors on post page

Tags: plugins, functions, theme-development

I am trying to make my theme compatible with [Co-Authors Plus plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/co-authors-plus/) and show the co-authors of a post if had any.
I spent about 30 minutes trying to convince myself that I understood the following code to display post author and date:

```php
function posted_on() {
    global $post;
    $author_id=$post->post_author;
    $time_string = '<time class="entry-date published updated" datetime="%1$s">%2$s</time>';
    if ( get_the_time( 'U' ) !== get_the_modified_time( 'U' ) ) {
        $time_string = '<time class="entry-date published" datetime="%1$s">%2$s</time><time class="updated" datetime="%3$s">%4$s</time>';
    }

    $time_string = sprintf( $time_string,
        esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ),
        esc_html( get_the_date() ),
        esc_attr( get_the_modified_date( 'c' ) ),
        esc_html( get_the_modified_date() )
    );


    $posted_on = sprintf(
        __( '<i class="entry-date">'. get_the_date( 'F d, Y' ) .'</i>' ),
        '<a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">' . $time_string . '</a>'
    );

    $byline = sprintf (
        __( 'by %s' ),


        '<span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="' . esc_url( 

            get_author_posts_url( $author_id )

        ) . '">' . esc_html( get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $author_id ) ) . '</a>' . '</span>'

    );



    echo '<span class="posted-on">' . $posted_on . '</span><i><span class="byline"> ' . $byline . '</span></i>'; // WPCS: XSS OK.
}
```

So I added a function:

```php
        $byline = sprintf(
            __('by %s'),

            /*Added this*/
            if (function_exists('coauthors_posts_links')) {
                '<span class="author vcard">'.esc_html(coauthors_posts_links()).
                '</span>'
            } else {

                '<span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="'.esc_url(

                    get_author_posts_url($author_id)

                ).
                '">'.esc_html(get_the_author_meta('display_name', $author_id)).
                '</a>'.
                '</span>'
            }

        );
```

The function was supposed to work like...

IF THIS POST POST CONTAINS CO-AUTHORS,

DISPLAY AUTHORS AND CO-AUTHORS.

IF POST DOESN'T CONTAIN CO-AUTHORS,

SHOW THE DEFAULT AUTHOR LINK.

But that just made error. Could use a little advice.

Comment: "But that just made error" - what's the error?

Comment: `esc_html(coauthors_posts_links())` - it looks like coauthors_posts_links echoes by default rather than returns a string. The ['incorporating into your theme'](https://wpvip.com/documentation/incorporate-co-authors-plus-template-tags-into-your-theme/) help page calls `coauthors_posts_links( null, null, null, null, false )` to get a return value. (And if the return value contains links I doubt you'd want to escape it.)

Comment: The error is "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in [WORDPRESS THEME DIRECTORY]/inc/template-tags.php on line 42 (here is line 42 `if (function_exists('coauthors_posts_links')) {`)"

Comment: Oh, I hadn’t noticed you’d written the if inside the sprintf argument list. You can’t do that - you could use a ?: ternary instead, or an if-else block to save the span HTML in a variable and use that in the sprintf.

Comment: How could I do that (the "?: ternary" one)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is that you've written an `if` inside the sprintf argument list. You can’t do that. Instead, you could use the [ternary operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary), which has syntax

```
<condition> ? <result if true> : <result if false>
```

e.g.

```
$byline = sprintf(
        __('by %s'),
        function_exists('coauthors_posts_links')
            ? ('<span class="author vcard">' .
                    coauthors_posts_links( null, null, null, null, false ) . '</span>')
            : ('<span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="'.esc_url(
                    get_author_posts_url($author_id)
                ).'">'.esc_html(get_the_author_meta('display_name', $author_id)).
                '</a>'.'</span>')
    );
```

(brackets added for clarity - you probably don't need them all)
or use a separate variable for the post links and set that first using an if-else, e.g.

```
if (function_exists('coauthors_posts_links')) {
    $author_post_links = coauthors_posts_links( null, null, null, null, false );
} else {
    $author_post_links = '<a class="url fn n" href="' .
        esc_url( get_author_posts_url( $author_id ) ) .
        '">' . esc_html( get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $author_id ) ) . '</a>';
}
$byline = sprintf(
    __('by %s'),
    '<span class="author vcard">' . $author_post_links . '</span>' );
```

As discussed in comments

- by default `coauthors_posts_links()` will echo the links as well as returning them as a string, which is not what you want here. You'll need to pass $echo = false, which is the fifth argument, so we'll need to fill in the previous four with default null values.
- I don't think you want to `esc_html()` the output of `coauthors_post_links()` so I've removed that too.

Comment: This code works but it creates duplicate links like this e.g.: Bob and Fredby Bob and Fred

Comment: My mistake - it needs the (null, null, null, null, false) arguments to coauthors_post_links that I mentioned in the question comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can create other function where you can store `function exists` code to make code easier to read like this.

```
   function custom_coauthors() 
    {
        $author = '';
        if (function_exists('coauthors_posts_links')) {
            $author .= '<span class="author vcard">' . esc_html(coauthors_posts_links()) . '</span>';
        } else {
            $author .= '<span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="'.esc_url( get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ))).'">' . esc_html(get_the_author_meta('display_name', $author_id)) . '</a>' . '</span>';
        }

        return $author;
    }

     $byline = sprintf(
        __('by %s'),
        custom_coauthors()
    );
```

You can also use `get_the_author_meta('ID')` to get the id of author.

Comment: This code makes the error: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare custom_coauthors()

Comment: Make sure you don't use same function name if you have any other function with same name. Try renaming the function